# qlikview How to get sheet name

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get all the object details using below code from an application i.e. Name and Id.

```
Sub Objects
    Shtobj = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.GetSheetObjects

    For i = LBound(Shtobj) To UBound(Shtobj)
        'MsgBox(Shtobj(i).GetObjectName)
        MsgBox(Shtobj(i).GetObjectId)
    Next
End Sub
```

But the `.GetObjectName` is not giving the me the name of the object.

Comment: Why VB.NET tag?

Comment: try `msgbox(Shtobj(i).Name)`. By the way, it looks more VBA than VBS

Comment: What application? What is the type of the objects? Do they even have a method or property `GetObjectName`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Hi, I am using the code in Qlikview appliation as a Macro. Application has different objects i.e. Text Box, List Box and Charts.With the above script I am getting ObjectID's correctly. But, not able to capture ObjectNames.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Sorry, it is my bad.

Comment: @lomed: Thanks for the replay. But, it is not working. "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Shtobj(...).Name'" this the error message I am getting..

Comment: Try `MsgBox(Shtobj(i).GetCaption.Name.v)`